# xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

when i install cuda-10.2 ubuntu-18.4 
my resolution be default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm

**`xrandr --output default --gamma 1:1:1 --mode 1280x720`**

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me quite often, be sure that you install nvidia drivers first (I would recommend some old but stable versions like 3xx). Unfortunately only full system reinstall helps.

Comment: how can i install nvidia driver

Comment: Here are two ways: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: i installed the new driver from terminal 
now the display has no any modes

Comment: this is from **`sudo lshw -C display`**

`*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108GLM [NVS 5200M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
`

Comment: You can try to fix it like in this tutorail: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124332/nvidia-low-res-after-update